# In Ruby when I set array X equal array Y and make chages to array X why is it also made to array Y?

Tags: arrays, ruby

In this code:

```
letters = %w{a b c d e f g}
letters_2 = letters

i = 0
while i < letters.length
    letters[i] = "X"
    puts "letters = " + letters.join
    puts "letters_2 = " + letters_2.join
    puts "======================"

    i+=1
end
```

why does **letters_2** array get changed when the code is only explicitly modifying the **letters** array?

Comment: Another way to think of it is that `letters` and `letters_2` are different names for the same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, there is only one array, and `letters` and `letters_2` are both assigned to it.

It sounds like what you want is for `letters_2` be a separate array, that's initialized from the `letters` array, but independent thereafter? If so, then one way to do that is to use [the `Array.new` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new):

```
letters = %w{a b c d e f g}
letters_2 = Array.new(letters)
# letters and letters_2 are now separate arrays with the same elements

letters[3] = "X" # this only affects letters, not letters_2
letters_2[4] = "Y" # this only affects letters_2, not letters
```

Comment: @sagarpandya82: Indeed. I'll rephrase my answer to avoid implying that there's only one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning the same reference there.

You can see here

```
letters = %w{a b c d e f g}
letters_2 = letters

puts letters.object_id    #4579428
puts letters_2.object_id  #4579428
```

So If you want to make the second one as separate array, then call 'dup' function when you assign the first array to the second,

```
letters = %w{a b c d e f g}
letters_2 = letters.dup
puts letters.object_id      #18932832
puts letters_2.object_id    #18932580
```

Comment: Since you've shown that the initial arrays are the same using `object_ id`, perhaps you could include the `object _id`s of the latter arrays to show that they are indeed different.

Comment: @sagarpandya82  Okay, Updated.

Answer (score 0):

you define only one array `letters`

than you have assign `letters` to `letters_2`.so you create create same array `letters_2` as `letters` .therefore any change made in `letters` will affect on `letters_2`.

both array refereeing same `object_id`

you can check that `letters.object_id` is same as `letters_2.object_id`

both array refer same memory address.

```
2.2.3 :038 > letters = %w{a b c d e f g}
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"] 
2.2.3 :039 > letters_2 = letters
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"] 
2.2.3 :040 > letters_2
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"] 
2.2.3 :041 > letters
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
```

Comment: This is what the OP described. The question is _why_ does a change affect both?

Comment: @Stefan both array refer same memory address.

Comment: You mention _"only one array"_ in your first sentence and later on _"both array[s]"_. That seems contradictory, it's not clear from your explanation if there is one array or two.

Comment: @Stefan i have edit my answer. Thanks for Suggestion.